# behaviors javascript executing

Tags: javascript

I want to pass params via Drupal to my JS file. I have no problem fetching them with the code below,
the problem is that as the  $(document).bind('leaflet.map'  function executes FIRST, it is not able to find the
user_name parameter

my_module.module

```
  function my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $user_name=$GLOBALS['user']->name;
  drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('user_name' => $user_name)), array('type' => 'setting'));
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/external.js');
  }
```

external.js

```
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.fewo_map= {

 attach: function (context, settings) {

 alert('get params');
 //we can fetch the data
 user_name=settings.fewo_map.user_name;
}
```

}

$(document).bind('leaflet.map', function(e, map, lMap) {

```
//it fires first, so is unable to get user_name data
alert('leaflet')

console.info(user_name)
})
```

If I do...

```
(function($) {

 Drupal.behaviors.fewo_map= {

 attach: function (context, settings) {

  $(document).bind('leaflet.map', function(e, map, lMap) {
    alert('leaflet')

    console.info(user_name)
    })
  }
 }
})
```

the result is the same

Also tried using JS injector, no success neither. I need the user_name as parameter to define the settings inside leaflet 'function'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to separate your php from javascript, but if you set js variable with this php code it should execute first and can be used within leaflet js function later:

```
<?php render('<script>var username = "'.$GLOBALS['user'].'";</script>'); ?>
```